# Select Rows and Columns At the Same Time in SPSS

Tags: r, spss

I have a dataset in SPSS that has 100K+ rows and over 100 columns.  I want to filter both the rows and columns at the same time into a new SPSS dataset.

I can accomplish this very easily using the `subset` command in R.  For example:

```
new_data = subset(old_data, select = ColumnA >10, select = c(ColumnA, ColumnC, ColumnZZ))
```

Even easier would be:

```
new data  = old_data[old_data$ColumnA >10, c(1, 4, 89)]
```

where I am passing the column indices instead.

What is the equivalent in SPSS?

I love R, but the read/write and data management speed of SPSS is significantly better.

Comment: you are incorrect about SPSS doing anything better than R

Comment: IF the read/write and data management speed of SPSS is significantly better AND you really enjoy doing read/write and data management OR your purpose in life is doing read/write and data management AND NOT doing real analysis of data THEN use SPSS ELSE use R.

Comment: Doing a select * from a database, aggregating, and creating sequence indicators are significantly faster.  Beyond that, I avoid SPSS at all costs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are referring to when you write that "the read/write and data management speed of SPSS being significantly better" than R. Your question itself demonstrates how flexible R is at data management! And, a dataset of 100k rows and 100 columns is by no means a large one.

But, to answer your question, perhaps you are looking for something like this. I'm providing a "programmatic" solution, rather than the GUI one, because you're asking the question on Stack Overflow, where the focus is more on the programming side of things. I'm using a sample data file that can be found here: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/examples/chp/p004.sav

Save that file to your SPSS working directory, open up your SPSS syntax editor, and type the following:

```
GET FILE='p004.sav'.
SELECT IF (lactatio <= 3).
SAVE OUTFILE= 'mynewdatafile.sav'
  /KEEP currentm previous lactatio.
GET FILE='mynewdatafile.sav'.
```

More likely, though, you'll have to go through something like this:

```
FILE HANDLE directoryPath /NAME='C:\path\to\working\directory\' . 
FILE HANDLE myFile /NAME='directoryPath/p004.sav' . 
GET FILE='myFile'.
SELECT IF (lactatio <= 3).
SAVE OUTFILE= 'directoryPath/mynewdatafile.sav'
  /KEEP currentm previous lactatio.
FILE HANDLE myFile /NAME='directoryPath/mynewdatafile.sav'.
GET FILE='myFile'.
```

You should now have a new file created that has just three columns, and where no value in the "lactatio" column is greater than 3.

So, the basic steps are:

1. Load the data you want to work with.
2. Subset for all columns from all the cases you're interested in.
3. Save a new file with only the variables you're interested in.
4. Load that new file before you proceed.

With R, the basic steps are:

1. Load the data you want to work with.
2. Create an object with your subset of rows and columns (which you know how to do).

Hmm.... I don't know about you, but I know which method *I* prefer ;)

If you're using the right tools with R, you can also directly *read in* the specific subset you are interested in without first loading the whole dataset if speed really is an issue.

Comment: As I suspected, you have to create temp files.  Thanks for the great response!

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complicated. I agree about R being better in many ways, but this is not a fair picture of SPSS capabilities (see my answer for a better one)

Answer (score 0):

In spss you can't combine the two actions in one command, but it's easy enough to do it in two:

```
dataset copy old_data. /* delete this if you don't need to keep both old and new data.
select if ColumnA>10.
add files /file=* /keep=ColumnA ColumnC ColumnZZ.
```